# .NET ORMLite and Eager Loading

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, ormlite-servicestack

I am planning to use a more lightweight ORM tool (so frustrated using EF mainly because of performance and memory usage) for my project.
  I am thinking of using ORMLite, it seems to be very neat ORM package.

The only thing I have not been able to figure out how to workaround **eager loading** related Models.

```
public class Account
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string CreatedById { get; set; }

     public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Using the class above I like to be able to load some fields on the related "CreatedBy" field as well.

```
SELECT Id, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name FROM Account
```

Eager Loading the references is very crucial since one database query can load hundreds of record and yet I would be able to show who created the record in a grid.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightweight orms don't contain features available in EF or nHibernate, there are fast but you must write more code. Eager loading doesn’t exist in ormlite.

But let’s start from beginning:) Your account class should looks like following:

```
public class Account
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string CreatedById { get; set; }

     [References(typeof(User))]
     public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
} 
public class User
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can't have property CreatedBy of User type - service stack ormlite doesn’t support this. Your class must looks like your table and in table you have int column of the name CreatedBy;) 
Here you can read how to make join from ormlite- [JoinSqlBuilder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/120)

Comment: Considering that I learnt how to use the JoinSqlBuilder where the selected columns are going to be populated if I don't have the "CreatedBy" property? 

- Secondly is there a way to further customize ORMLite to support basic Eager Loading?

Comment: Regarding JoinSqlBuilder you could create new type(yes I know it's stupid) or you can add one more property of type User to Account class with [Ignore] attribute and then fulfill this property. In my opinion to create nice Eager Loading you must change ormlite source code to add this feature.

Comment: In order to make sure no one else misunderstands your answer let's remove the INT property you added, the Foreign key is "CreatedById".
I appreciate your response.

Comment: I think any ORM system requires basic support for handling relational database mapping to models. I will look into what would it take to add the feature to ORMLite.